# Is there a file type for APL programs?

Tags: apl

Is there a way to open up a text editor, type up some APL code, save it as a file, and then open it in Dyalog or MicroAPLX to execute the code? Or is that what workspaces are?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

APL was invented well before the widespread availability of file systems and text editors. Therefore it provided its own facilities to store and edit code (functions) and data, namely Workspaces and Component files. Most commercial APL systems of today still provide them, for continuity with existing installations and with developer expertise.

But those facilities date back to half a century ago and were designed for the hardware and interfaces of the time (mainframes and teletypes) which are to modern hardware as hand crank telephones are to smartphones.

Nowadays most developers would argue that code is best kept in (UTF-8 encoded) text files, edited with [one's text editor of choice](http://www.sublimetext.com/), and managed with a distributed version control system. I certainly subscribe to this view.

Some of the classical APL vendors have kept their offers "up to date" in this regard and provide facilities to deal with source code files, in a manner hopefully not too disjoint from workspaces. Dyalog APL has such a library called [SALT - Simple APL Library Toolkit](http://docs.dyalog.com/12.1/SALT.pdf).

But the truth is, most APL systems don't have an easy command or function to load a source file because it's simply not used in practice. APL developers regard their APL system as an IDE, almost an OS. They keep everything inside workspaces and just use the editing windows provided by the system.

IMHO newer APL implementations (such as [GNU APL](https://www.gnu.org/software/apl/) and others) will eventually reject the concept of workspaces and align themselves with "modern" practices. But this is just my view, which is certainly not shared by the majority of APL programmers. Ask any of them about it and you will hear something along the lines of: *≪You can have my workspaces and component files when you pry them from my cold, dead fingers.≫*

Comment: I have been using APL for 35+ years and am (still) looking forward to the end of the Workspace as the primary code storage medium.  Among other things, code is imprisoned in a vendor's proprietary workspace format and is easily lost when the source interpreter is lost or for whatever reasons not available.  But I agree with Tobia as this may not be the usual opinion.

Answer (score 7):

@Tobia already gave a good answer regarding APL in general, but I would like to add some details concering what you can do with [GNU APL](http://www.gnu.org/software/apl/) and [Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/). With the [GNU APL mode](https://github.com/lokedhs/gnu-apl-mode) for Emacs (I am the author of this mode) you can keep APL code in source files (with the `.apl` extension) and execute code directly from the files. There is also some basic code navigation features (`M-.` moves to the location where a function was defined).

There is still work to be done to improve things but I would love to get comments as to what features people would want to see added.

Answer (score 4):

Dyalog 14.0 has a command line option for scripts.  On a Unix-like platform the first line of an executable script file could be

```
#!/path/to/dyalog -script
```

Comment: This gives me "not a ws". Is there something I'm not aware of?

Comment: @Ven The script needs to be piped in rather than given as argument.

Answer (score 1):

## Update for 2022

Both Dyalog APL and GNU APL now support #! scripting.

- **GNU APL:** `#! /usr/local/bin/apl --script` in a .apl file [<sup>DOCS</sup>](https://www.gnu.org/software/apl/apl.html#Make-the-script-file-executable)
- **Dyalog APL:** `#! dyalogscript` in a .apls file [<sup>DOCS</sup>](https://help.dyalog.com/latest/#UserGuide/Installation%20and%20Configuration/Shell%20Scripts.htm)

Note that .apls files are also executable under Windows.

Answer (score 0):

No, there was never a single file type for APL workspaces.  APL was always and still is very vendor-dependent - each vendor had its own internal format and file extensions for workspaces.  Some extensions were .DWS, .W3, .WS, just to name a few.  APL language features aside, the proprietary internal formats used by the various vendors were profoundly different and wildly incompatible.  Further, a newer APL interpreter might be unable to open an older workspace past a certain vintage, for example, a newer Dyalog 16.0 interpreter would be unable to open a workspaces saved with Dyalog Version 8.0.  The same was true with APL+2000.

Offhand, the only system-level compatibility I can think of for workspaces from the same vendor was the )MCOPY command in Mainframe IBM APL2, where APL2 could directly read the older VSAPL workspaces.  Otherwise, there was plenty of good APL migration software to handle this.